# Getting a closed form from $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1$

Tags: summation, closed-form, arithmetic-progressions, summation-method

I need to get a closed form from

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1
$$

Starting from the most outer summation, I got

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 = j
$$

But now I don't know how to proceed with:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j
$$

Could you guys please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the change of variables $k = j - i$ to change the inner summation $\sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{n-i} k + i$, which is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-i} k + (n-i)i $; this should be more doable. Do something similar for the last summation!

Comment: [$1+2+\ldots+n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and [$1^2+2^2+\ldots+ n^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

Comment: Also remember that by writing $n^3 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 - (k-1)^3$ - this is a trick called a "telescoping sum" - and observing that $k^3 - (k-1)^3 = k^3 - (k^3 - 3k^2 + 3k - 1)$, using binomial expansion on $(k-1)^3$, we can write $n^3 = \sum_{k=1}^n 3k^2 - 3k + 1$. (This may look complicated, but it is doable, and you should check that it is true.) The point is this: you can then write $n^3 + \sum_{k=1}^n 3k + 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n 3k^2$. By using what you know about $\sum_{k=1}^n 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k$, *you can evaluate* $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$!

Comment: Getting the hints from this question as well as some other questions, I tried in this way:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j$$
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} j$$
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n} j \cdot n + j$$

And so I got:

$$\frac{n^2+n-2}{2}+n \cdot \frac{n^2+n-2}{2}$$
$$\frac{n^3+2n^2n-n-2}{2}$$

Can you guys please help me finding where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Winther for pointing out the previous mistake

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1
\end{equation}
We know that 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 = j
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 =
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j
 =
 \sum_{j=1}^{n} j
 -
 \sum_{j=1}^{i} j
 =
 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
 -
 \frac{i(i+1)}{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 =
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} ( \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
 -
 \frac{i(i+1)}{2})
 =
 \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{2}
 -
 \frac{1}{2}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}
 i+i^2
\end{equation}
But
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}
 i &= \frac{(n-1)n}{2} \\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}
 i^2 &= \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}
\end{align}
So
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 =
 \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{2}
 -
 \frac{1}{2}
 (\frac{(n-1)n}{2} + \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6})
\end{equation}
Let's arrange
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 =
\frac{6n(n+1)(n-1) - 3n(n-1) - n(n-1)(2n-1)}{12}
\end{equation}

> We arrive at the most compact form,
>   \begin{equation}
>  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1 =
> \frac{(n-1)n(6n + 6 - 3 - 2n + 1)}{12}
> =
> \frac{(n-1)n(n + 1)}{3}
> \end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n\sum_{k=1}^j1
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}\sum_{k=1}^{j+i}1\tag1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}(j+i)\tag2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-i+1}2+i(n-i)\tag3\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{i+1}2+i(n-i)\tag4\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left[n\binom{i}{1}-\binom{i}{2}\right]\tag5\\[3pt]
&=n\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{3}\tag6\\[6pt]
&=(n+1)\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n+1}{3}\tag7\\[3pt]
&=3\binom{n+1}{3}-\binom{n+1}{3}\tag8\\[6pt]
&=2\binom{n+1}{3}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $j\mapsto j+i$
$(2)$: evaluate the inner sum
$(3)$: evaluate the inner sum
$(4)$: substitute $i\mapsto n-i$
$(5)$: recombine terms
$(6)$: sum the binomial coefficients
$(7)$: add $\binom{n}{2}$ to both terms of the difference
$(8)$: $\frac{n+1}3\binom{n}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}$
$(9)$: evaluate the difference

Comment: Any clue about the downvote?

Comment: I didnt understand the first step. Why the upper bound of the second summation changes from $n$ to $n-i$?

Comment: @DiegoMarques: after the substitution $j\mapsto j+i$, the summation starts at $j+i=i+1$ and ends at $j+i=n$; that is, it starts at $j=1$ and ends at $j=n-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1) &= n \\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= \frac{n \, (n+1)}{2} \\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} (1) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} j - \sum_{j=1}^{i} i \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\binom{n}{2} - \frac{i(i+1)}{2}\right)  \\
&= \binom{n}{2} \, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (1) - \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 - \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \\
&= \binom{n}{2} \, (n-1) - \frac{n(n-1)}{4} - \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{12} \\
&= \frac{(n-1)(n)(n+1)}{3} = 2 \, \binom{n+1}{3}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Sum by sum:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{j} 1&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} j=\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i+1+n}{2}\cdot (n-i-1+1)=\\
&=\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} n^2+n-i^2-i=\\
&=\frac12\left[(n^2+n)(n-1)-\frac{(n-1)n(2(n-1)+1)}{6}-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\right]=\\
&=\frac12n(n-1)\left[n+1-\frac{2n-1}{3}-1\right]=\\
&=\frac12n(n-1)\cdot \frac{n+1}{3}.\end{align}$$